# NLP using XLM dataset

Tags: python, pandas, xml, jupyter-notebook, nlp

I am trying to do NLP on the dataset consisting of the following row

```
00001 B 74457
00002 C 12804123 16026213 14627885
00004 A 15329425 9058342 11279767
```

where 1st element in the row is the identifier  2nd on is a label recommends, it can have only three labels $A, B, C$ and the number for examples 12804123 represent the id of the XML, it contains data, for example, text, location, etc. Based on this I need to extract the data from the XML file and use it to make a model. So first of all I want to extract some of the data from the XML file and make a data frame of structure data. An example of the XML file is below.
When I run the command pd.read_xml(xml) it gives

```
    medlinecitation     pubmeddata
0   NaN     NaN
```

Any example from Kaggle or any other source etc I can follow to do the analysis.

```
74457.xml = '''
<pubmedarticleset>
<pubmedarticle>
<medlinecitation owner="NLM" status="MEDLINE">
<pmid version="1"> 74457 </pmid>
<datecreated>
<year> 1978 </year>
<month> 03 </month>
<day> 21 </day>
</datecreated>
<datecompleted>
<year> 1978 </year>
<month> 03 </month>
<day> 21 </day>
</datecompleted>
<daterevised>
<year> 2007 </year>
<month> 11 </month>
<day> 15 </day>
</daterevised>
<article pubmodel="Print">
<journal>
<issn issntype="Print"> 0140-6736 </issn>
<journalissue citedmedium="Print">
<volume> 1 </volume>
<issue> 7984 </issue>
<pubdate>
<year> 1976 </year>
<month> Sep </month>
<day> 4 </day>
</pubdate>
</journalissue>
<title> Lancet </title>
<isoabbreviation> Lancet </isoabbreviation>
</journal>
<articletitle>
Prophylactic treatment of alcoholism by lithium carbonate. A controlled study.
</articletitle>
<pagination>
<medlinepgn> 481-2 </medlinepgn>
</pagination>
<abstract>
<abstracttext>
Lithium therapy has been shown to have a therapeutic influence in reducing the drinking and incapacity by alcohol in depressive alcoholics in a prospective double-blind placebo-controlled trial conducted over one year, but it had no significant effect on non-depressed patients. Patients in the trial treated by placebo had significantly greater alcoholic morbidity if they were depressive than if they were non-depressive.
</abstracttext>
</abstract>
<authorlist completeyn="Y">
<author validyn="Y">
<lastname> Merry </lastname>
<forename> J </forename>
<initials> J </initials>
</author>
<author validyn="Y">
<lastname> Reynolds </lastname>
<forename> C M </forename>
<initials> CM </initials>
</author>
<author validyn="Y">
<lastname> Bailey </lastname>
<forename> J </forename>
<initials> J </initials>
</author>
<author validyn="Y">
<lastname> Coppen </lastname>
<forename> A </forename>
<initials> A </initials>
</author>
</authorlist>
<language> eng </language>
<publicationtypelist>
<publicationtype> Clinical Trial </publicationtype>
<publicationtype> Comparative Study </publicationtype>
<publicationtype> Journal Article </publicationtype>
<publicationtype> Randomized Controlled Trial </publicationtype>
</publicationtypelist>
</article>
<medlinejournalinfo>
<country> ENGLAND </country>
<medlineta> Lancet </medlineta>
<nlmuniqueid> 2985213R </nlmuniqueid>
<issnlinking> 0140-6736 </issnlinking>
</medlinejournalinfo>
<chemicallist>
<chemical>
<registrynumber> 0 </registrynumber>
<nameofsubstance> Placebos </nameofsubstance>
</chemical>
<chemical>
<registrynumber> 7439-93-2 </registrynumber>
<nameofsubstance> Lithium </nameofsubstance>
</chemical>
</chemicallist>
<citationsubset> AIM </citationsubset>
<citationsubset> IM </citationsubset>
<meshheadinglist>
<meshheading>
<descriptorname majortopicyn="N"> Adult </descriptorname>
</meshheading>
<meshheading>
<descriptorname majortopicyn="N"> Alcohol Drinking </descriptorname>
</meshheading>
<meshheading>
<descriptorname majortopicyn="N"> Alcoholism </descriptorname>
<qualifiername majortopicyn="Y"> drug therapy </qualifiername>
</meshheading>
<meshheading>
<descriptorname majortopicyn="N"> Clinical Trials as Topic </descriptorname>
</meshheading>
<meshheading>
<descriptorname majortopicyn="N"> Depression </descriptorname>
<qualifiername majortopicyn="N"> chemically induced </qualifiername>
<qualifiername majortopicyn="Y"> prevention & control </qualifiername>
</meshheading>
<meshheading>
<descriptorname majortopicyn="N"> Double-Blind Method </descriptorname>
</meshheading>
<meshheading>
<descriptorname majortopicyn="N"> Drug Evaluation </descriptorname>
</meshheading>
<meshheading>
<descriptorname majortopicyn="N"> Female </descriptorname>
</meshheading>
<meshheading>
<descriptorname majortopicyn="N"> Humans </descriptorname>
</meshheading>
<meshheading>
<descriptorname majortopicyn="N"> Lithium </descriptorname>
<qualifiername majortopicyn="Y"> therapeutic use </qualifiername>
</meshheading>
<meshheading>
<descriptorname majortopicyn="N"> Male </descriptorname>
</meshheading>
<meshheading>
<descriptorname majortopicyn="N"> Middle Aged </descriptorname>
</meshheading>
<meshheading>
<descriptorname majortopicyn="N"> Placebos </descriptorname>
</meshheading>
</meshheadinglist>
</medlinecitation>
<pubmeddata>
<history>
<pubmedpubdate pubstatus="pubmed">
<year> 1976 </year>
<month> 9 </month>
<day> 4 </day>
</pubmedpubdate>
<pubmedpubdate pubstatus="medline">
<year> 1976 </year>
<month> 9 </month>
<day> 4 </day>
<hour> 0 </hour>
<minute> 1 </minute>
</pubmedpubdate>
<pubmedpubdate pubstatus="entrez">
<year> 1976 </year>
<month> 9 </month>
<day> 4 </day>
<hour> 0 </hour>
<minute> 0 </minute>
</pubmedpubdate>
</history>
<publicationstatus> ppublish </publicationstatus>
<articleidlist>
<articleid idtype="pubmed"> 74457 </articleid>
</articleidlist>
</pubmeddata>
</pubmedarticle>
</pubmedarticleset>'''
```

Please help me to understand what is happening? And how can I make it a data frame?

Comment: Did you try to read the documentation? Do you understand what it says about the expected format for the XML?

Comment: What I understand is that there is a '<pmid version="1"> 74457 </pmid>' I need to make a df with this as unique identifier and make columns with some of the information I feel important like " abstract' , 'country' etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```py
import pandas as pd

try:
    medlinecitation = pd.read_xml("74457.xml", xpath=".//medlinecitation").dropna(
        axis=1
    )
except ValueError:
    medlinecitation = pd.DataFrame()

try:
    pubmedpubdate = pd.read_xml("74457.xml", xpath=".//pubmedpubdate")
except ValueError:
    pubmedpubdate = pd.DataFrame()

df = pd.merge(
    left=medlinecitation,
    right=pubmedpubdate,
    how="outer",
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True,
).fillna(method="ffill")
```

```py
print(df)
# Output
  owner   status     pmid citationsubset pubstatus  year  month  day  hour  \
0   NLM  MEDLINE  74457.0             IM    pubmed  1976      9    4   NaN   
1   NLM  MEDLINE  74457.0             IM   medline  1976      9    4   0.0   
2   NLM  MEDLINE  74457.0             IM    entrez  1976      9    4   0.0   

   minute  
0     NaN  
1     1.0  
2     0.0
```

Comment: Can you please modify the code such that suppose the file doesn't contain either medlinecation or pubmedpubdate etc then it can return some empty data set? And it won't give error?

Comment: Done, see my updated answer. Cheers.